# How to extract url GET parameter from <a> tag, from the full html text

Tags: python, html, regex

So I have an html page. It's full of various  tags, most of them have sessionid GET parameter in their href attribute. Example:

```
...
<a href="struct_view_distrib.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...
<a href="SHOW_PARENT.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...
<a href="nakl_view.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...
<a href="move_sum_to_7300001.asp?sessionid=11692390&mode_id=0">
...
```

So, as you see, sessionid is the same, i just need to get it's value into variable, no matter from which one: x=11692390
I'm newbie in regex, but google wasn't helpful. Thx a lot!

Comment: Do not use RegEx to parse HTML. Obligatory Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This does not use regexes, but anyway, this is what you would do in Python 2.6:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.findAll('a', href=True)

for link in links:
  href = link['href']
  url = urlparse.urlparse(href)
  params = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query)
  if 'sessionid' in params:
    print params['sessionid'][0]
```

Comment: +l for `urlparse`, this library is wonderful and it would be a real shame to try and solve a problem like this without it

Comment: `import urllib.parse` and `urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(href).query)` in python3

Answer (score 5):

Parse your HTML with a DOM parsing library and use `getElementsByTagName('a')` to grab anchors, iterate through them and use `getAttribute('href')` and then extract the string. Then you can use regex or split on `?` to match/retrieve the session id.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this - before I was told it was a python issue ;)

```
<script>
function parseQString(loc) {
  var qs = new Array();
  loc = (loc == null) ? location.search.substring(1):loc.split('?')[1];
  if (loc) {
    var parms = loc.split('&');
    for (var i=0;i<parms.length;i++) {
      nameValue = parms[i].split('=');
      qs[nameValue[0]]=(nameValue.length == 2)? unescape(nameValue[1].replace(/\+/g,' ')):null; // use null or ""
    }
  }
  return qs;
}
var ids = []; // will hold the IDs
window.onload=function() {
  var links = document.links;
  var id;
  for (var i=0, n=links.length;i<n;i++) {
    ids[i] = parseQString(links[i].href)["sessionid"];
  }
  alert(ids); // remove this when happy
  // here you can do 
  alert(ids[3]); 
  //to get the 4th link's sessionid
}


</script>

<a href="struct_view_distrib.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...</a>
<a href="SHOW_PARENT.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...</a>
<a href="nakl_view.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...</a>
<a href="move_sum_to_7300001.asp?sessionid=11692390&mode_id=0">
...</a>
```

Comment: Erm okee, so where did the python rear its head? Not tagged as such when I answered

Comment: sorry, my first question here, i thought question was only about regexes and forget to tag it for python also

Comment: Interesting. So, there is no standard way to parse a uri in browser js?

Comment: @Constantin: what do you mean? location.protocol, location.hostName, location.port, location.href, location.search, location.hash is what you can use, but location.search and .hash are strings that are not further atomised

Answer (score 1):

Below is an regex you can use to match hrefs and extract its value:

```
\b(?<=(href="))[^"]*?(?=")
```

Comment: I wouldn't encourage using regular expressions to grab the attributes. Won't vote it down, but I wouldn't want to upvote it either.

Comment: Unless the DOM was not accessible, I completely agree.
You have document.links[x].href and document.getElementsByTagName("a")[x].href right off the bat without using jQuery or regExp

Comment: Yes I completely agree regex is bad idea to parse html. If you see my previous regex answers, I have been telling this to every one. Now since someone already said this in another answer before me, and that I am tired of saying same thing again and again I just put the regex here.

Answer (score 1):

Complete example for Python3, inspired by AbdealiJK:

```
response = """...
<a href="struct_view_distrib.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...
<a href="SHOW_PARENT.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...
<a href="nakl_view.asp?sessionid=11692390">
...
<a href="move_sum_to_7300001.asp?sessionid=11692390&mode_id=0">
..."""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    try:
        print(urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(i['href']).query)["sessionid"])
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

bs4 4.7.1.+ has all the functionality you need for this. Use css AND syntax combined with `:not` to specify url with param sessionid only and select_one to limit to first match, then split on that param and grab the ubound array value

```
soup.select_one("[href*='asp?sessionid']:not([href*='&'])")['href'].split('sessionid=')[-1]
```